# Unicode across the network to xml

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure out the safest way to retrieve unicode data in a unified method from remote computers and make sure that data stays consistent and readable.

Computer A: Chinese user, mixed English Windows 7, some registry values contain Chinese letters like L"您好"

Computer B: US English, no unicode values returned from my functions

Computer C: Introduces an agent to Computer A and B.

The agent: assesses the health and security of the computer from the inside.  One unicode aware section is simply getting registry values i.e:

```
int Utilities::GetRegistryStringValue(HKEY h_sub_key, WCHAR* value_name, wstring &result)
{
DWORD cbData = 8;
LPDWORD type = NULL;

//Get the size and type of the key
long err = RegQueryValueEx(h_sub_key, value_name, NULL, type, NULL, &cbData);

if (err != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    if (err != ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
        debug->DebugMessage(Error::GetErrorMessageW(err));
    return err;
}

result.resize(cbData / sizeof(WCHAR));

LPWSTR res = new WCHAR[(cbData + sizeof(L'\0')) / sizeof(WCHAR)];

err = RegQueryValueEx(h_sub_key, value_name, NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE) &res[0], &cbData);

if(err != ERROR_SUCCESS && err != ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
{
    debug->DebugMessage(Error::GetErrorMessageW(err));
    return err;
}

res[cbData / sizeof(WCHAR)] = L'\0';

result = wstring(res);

return ERROR_SUCCESS;
```

}

Those values will be stored in an XML file.
Should that XML file be in UTF16 or UTF8?
Am I going to need to pass the remote system's code page back for translation?
What other issues might I have?

Comment: btw, I need a small, small executable.  Introducing ICU or equiv unicode libraries should be avoided but not out of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTF8 is more standard (for networking) because it does not have endian issues.  For UTF16 you'll need to specify an endian-ness for the transmission.  If you're using a unicode format, you do *not* need a code page.

You can do the translation with standard windows calls like [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) if they're on windows machines.

```
std::wstring buffer_with_utf16;
const char DefaultChar = 1; //not null, but not normal either
bool had_conversion_error = false;    
int alength = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, 
              buffer_with_utf16.cstr(), buffer_with_utf16.size(),
              NULL, 0, 
              &DefaultChar, &had_conversion_error);
if (alength == 0)
    throw std::logic_error("Bad UTF8 conversion"); //use GetLastError
std::string buffer_with_utf8(alength+1);
int error = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, 
              buffer_with_utf16.cstr(), buffer_with_utf16.size(),
              &buffer_with_utf8[0], buffer_with_utf8.size(), 
              &DefaultChar, &had_conversion_error);
if (error == 0)
    throw std::logic_error("Bad UTF8 conversion"); //use GetLastError
```

Comment: I do do that.  Is there any danger that I might not be able to convert some unicode characters?

Comment: Is there any way that I can force those WINAPI functions to return UTF8 instead?

Comment: Also, when I'm generating the XML, my problem is that it would reach a Chinese character and stop writing.  I found that the reason for this is that you can't guarantee xml_outfile << L"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?>"; will be UTF16 or UTF8 or whatever ... How can I make that guarantee?

Comment: All official Unicode characters can be properly formatted in UTF8/16/32.  ASCII is a subset of UTF8, so you can pretend strings containing only characters <127 are UTF8 already.  Wide strings will be sometimes UTF16LE, and sometimes UTF16BE on windows, and will be UTF32 on linux.

Comment: Also good to note that Windows says `UNICODE` it really means UTF16LE (wide chars).  In reality, UTF8 is _also_ a form of unicode (which uses thin chars).